# Git push a branch by https url in bash

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am writing a bash script in azure pipeline to create a new branch and then push it to azure devops repo. Since it is a private repo, I have to use the https URL to incorporate the system token to authenticate the push. However, I got error when performing git push.

I tried with two different syntax but both got errors:

```
git push "https://$SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@dev.azure.com/company/reponame/_git/java-_microservice?version=GBfeat%2FSC-999-template-Reponame"

fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
  asked for: https://***@dev.azure.com/company/reponame/_git/java-_microservice?version=GBfeat%2FSC-999-template-java-_microservice/info/refs&service=git-receive-pack
   redirect: https://spsprodweu1.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signin?realm=dev.azure.com&reply_to=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.azure.com%2Fcompany%2Freponame%2F_git%2Fjava-_microservice%3Fversion%3DGBfeat%252FSC-999-template-java-_microservice%252Finfo%252Frefs%26service%3Dgit-receive-pack&redirect=1&hid=39b7d696-fa4d-4520-
```

```
git push "https://$SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@dev.azure.com/company/reponame/_git/java-_microservice feat/SC-999-template-$Reponame"

fatal: unable to access 'https://dev.azure.com/company/reponame/_git/java-_microservice feat/SC-999-template-java-_microservice/': The requested URL returned error: 400
```

I can perform a similar push to the main but not to a branch, could you help to shed some lights?

Comment: `git remote add origin https://...` and `git push -u origin master`?

Comment: `main` _is_ a branch (and if that's not the case for you, then we need more information). What do you mean?

Comment: thanks Pieterjan, I will try to separate it into 2 commands

Comment: eftshift0 - I can push to the main branch but not the feature branch like feat/999-name

Comment: Don't put credentials in the URL because it's easy for them to leak that way.  Instead, [use the technique to read credentials from the environment outlined in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-credentials-environment).

Answer (score 0):

The message:

```
fatal: unable to update url base from redirection
```

is telling you that Git sent a cURL library request for a particular URL, and the *server for that URL* said "no, don't ask ME about that, go over to this other web site URL and ask THEM about that".

Git won't go over to another URL like this, because you may have sensitive data (including a user name and password) that this would give to someone you were not expecting.  Git assumes that if you meant to go to that other URL, you would have *used* that other URL yourself.

If your system *requires* that you go through this other URL, do that yourself.

If you're not expecting this kind of redirect in the first place, find out why you are getting it.

Note that the redirect you're getting begins with:

```
https://spsprodweu1.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signin?
```

which means `visualstudio.com` is trying to force you to log in to *them* before they'll let you access `https://***@dev.azure.com/company/reponame/_git/java-_microservice?...`.  That strongly suggests that the authentication token you're using is the wrong one.